# Export of Metadata in layout.tsx not building in NextJS. The build thinks it is a client side file which is incorrect

Tags: next.js, metadata

Why won't my components/layout.tsx build? It is complaining about the metadata being exported. The file is not marked as 'use client'.

Failed to compile.

./components/layout.tsx
ReactServerComponentsError:

You are attempting to export "metadata" from a component marked with "use client", which is disallowed. Either remove the export, or the "use client" directive. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#the-use-client-directive

```
/Users/arscroggin/code/earhart-app/components/layout.tsx:4:1

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })
 
// export of metadata not working...
export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: 'MindScout',
    description: 'A Mental Health Platform That Matters More',
```

Here is my components/layout.tsx file

```
import { Metadata } from 'next';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

// export of metadata not working...
export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: 'MindScout',
    description: 'A Mental Health Platform'
}

export default function Layout({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode
}) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
        </html>
  )
}
```

I have followed the steps in the NextJS tutorial for setting up static metadata and every file includes the Layout.tsx file. I do not understand why the NextJS build process thinks it is a client side file.

Comment: hey were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: Yes. I took a different approach to my Layout.tsx and it now works as expected.